# Cannot access protected member in base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, protected

Consider you have the following code:

```
public abstract class MenuItem
    {
        protected string m_Title;
        protected int m_Level;
        protected MenuItem m_ParentItem;
        public event ChooseEventHandler m_Click;

        protected MenuItem(string i_Title, int i_Level, MenuItem i_ParentItem)
        {
            m_Title = i_Title;
            m_Level = i_Level;
            m_ParentItem = i_ParentItem;
        }
}
```

and

```
public class ContainerItem : MenuItem
    {
    private List<MenuItem> m_SubMenuItems;

    public ContainerItem(string i_Title, int i_Level, MenuItem i_ParentItem)
                            :base(i_Title, i_Level, i_ParentItem)
    {
        m_SubMenuItems = new List<MenuItem>();
    }

    public string GetListOfSubItems()
    {
        string subItemsListStr = string.Empty;

        foreach (MenuItem item in m_SubMenuItems)
        {
           item.m_Title = "test";  // Cannot access protected member the qualifier   
                                  must be of type 'Ex04.Menus.Delegates.ContainerItem' 

        }

        return subItemsListStr;
    }
}
```

1. I really do not understand the logic behind this error, and yes I have already read:
   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/09/491031.aspx
   But I still see it totally illogical according to the definition of Protected Access modifier.
   I see it as should be accessible from the same class where it was defined which is `MenuItem` and for all its derived classes! (`ContainerItem` ,etc)
2. How would you access the protected members like `m_Title` while holding a reference to `MenuItem` (because of Polymorphism design reasons)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Why does this happen?

An answer that cannot be argued with is "because the spec [says so](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx)":

> A `protected` member of a base class is accessible in a derived class
>   *only if the access occurs through the derived class type*.

But let's explore this restriction behind the scenes.

#### Explanation

What happens here is the same thing that Eric Lippert describes in the blog post that you linked to. Your code does the equivalent of [this](http://ideone.com/iImqHo):

```
public abstract class MenuItem
{
    protected string m_Title;
}

public class ContainerItem : MenuItem
{
    void Foo()
    {
        var derivedItem = new ContainerItem();
        derivedItem.m_Title = "test"; // works fine

        var baseItem = (MenuItem)derived;
        baseItem.m_Title = "test"; // compiler error!
    }
}
```

The problem here stems from the fact that this might happen. For the moment, please disregard the fact that this example uses a method instead of a field -- we 'll come back to it.

```
public abstract class MenuItem
{
    protected void Foo() {}
}

public class SomeTypeOfItem : MenuItem
{
    protected override void Foo() {}
}

public class ContainerItem : MenuItem
{
    void Bar()
    {
        var baseItem = (MenuItem)something;
        baseItem.Foo(); // #1
    }
}
```

Look at line #1: how does the compiler know that `baseItem` is not actually a `SomeTypeOfItem`? If it is, you certainly must not be able to access `Foo`! So, as Eric describes, the compiler is unable to **statically prove** that the access is always legal and because of that it has to disallow this code.

Note that in some cases, for example if

```
baseItem = (MenuItem)new ContainerItem();
```

or even

```
baseItem = (MenuItem)this;
```

the compiler does have enough information to prove that the access is legal but it still will not allow the code to compile. I imagine that's because the compiler team is not convinced that implementing such special-case handlers is worth the trouble (a point of view which I am sympathetic to).

#### But... but...

That's all well and good for methods (and properties, which are really methods) -- what about fields? What about this:

```
public abstract class MenuItem
{
    protected string m_Title;
}

public class SomeTypeOfItem : MenuItem
{
    protected new string m_Title;
}

public class ContainerItem : MenuItem
{
    void Foo()
    {
        var baseItem = (MenuItem)something;
        baseItem.m_Title = "Should I be allowed to change this?"; // #1
    }
}
```

Since fields cannot be overridden, there should be no ambiguity here and the code should compile and set `MenuItem.m_Title` irrespective of what the type of `something` is.

Indeed, I cannot think of a *technical* reason why the compiler couldn't do this, but there is a good reason in any case: consistency. Eric himself would probably be able to provide a richer explanation.

#### So what can I do?

> How would you access the protected members like m_Title while holding
>   a reference to MenuItem (because of Polymorphism design reasons)?

You simply cannot do that; you would have to make the members `internal` (or `public`).

Comment: superb answer! I guess it is more logical to add public property for each protected member, what do you think?
Is there a difference between public members vs private or protected members with public properties?

Comment: @JavaSa: I edited the answer because the previous version wasn't quite satisfactory -- please have a look again. If you expose the fields through `public` properties there is absolutely no reason for the fields to be `protected`, I would consider that bad design.

Comment: Thanks but, I once told that members must not be public, and that they are always should be private.
The list I hold is having references to potentially diverse collection of different `MenuItem`s of many kinds, and all I wanted is to be able to get value of their already inherited members from the base class , no matter which concrete type it is. I want to be able to reach their value while looking them in a polymorphic manner (base class view)

Comment: @JavaSa I assume by "*members*" you mean fields as there are loads of reasons why properties should be public. In your scenario, the Title field is obviously required outside the scope of the class itself therefore it *should* be a public property. If the actual setting of the data is what you are concerned about then make that private, not the property itself.

Comment: @JavaSa: Yes, "no reason to be `protected`" means that they should be `private`. The properties themselves of course will be either `public` or `internal`, depends on what makes sense for the design.

Comment: Good answer which clarifies why it doesn't work. I can't understand why they decided to go this route however. It's very common to have a hierarchy where you want protected data in the base which derived types collaborate on, which you don't want to make public.

Comment: "If it is, you certainly must not be able to access `Foo`!"
There isn't a technical reason why you can't access `Foo` in that case just like the fields example. I think the rule is there to keep protected members from being accessed by a class that is not derived from it, in this case a sibling class.

Answer (score 3):

`protected` does mean that the derived class can access it, however, the derived class can access the property of it's own instance. In your example, you can access `this.m_Title` since that belongs to the instance itself, but you are attempting to access the protected member of another instance (i.e. the instance in the list `m_SubMenuItems`).

You need getter and setter methods to access it the way you're trying to.

Hopefully this makes it clearer:

```
class Foo {
    protected int x;

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}

class Bar : Foo {
    Foo myFoo = new Foo();

    public void someMethod() {
        this.x = 5;    // valid. You are accessing your own variable
        myFoo.x = 5;   // invalid. You are attempting to access the protected
                       // property externally
        myFoo.setX(5); // valid. Using a public setter
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the same false statement as the other answer. [Proof](http://ideone.com/qSTEbi) that it's false.

Comment: @Jon: Your proof is not operating with the same conditions as the code of the OP. The difference is: You have instances of `Derived`, he has instances of `Base`!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Of course it's not the same code. Mine was designed to show that it doesn't matter if you have different *instances*, what matters is *the static type* of those instances. The answers here say that what matters is the instances.

Comment: @Jon: Exactly, the static type matters. And that's the point here. He has a list of instances with the static type of `Base`. And that is the very reason why he can't access the protected member. He could cast it to `Derived`, but **only if** it really is an instance of that type - which is unknown.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Please see my own answer. I can't explain it any better than that.

Comment: @Jon: Well, I think we both agree that the declared type of the instance is relevant and not the instance in itself. Obviously, we both interpreted "another instance" in different ways. For me this implicitly contained the fact, that the "other instance" was of the static type `Base`. +1 on your answer.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: That's a fair assessment, and thanks for your vote.